# Overlaying lat/long graticules on projected map using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, latitude-longitude, grids-graticules

I am using an equal areas projection of North America and would like to overlay a lat/long grid.

I can do this in the print composer, but only for the coordinates.

Can QGIS do a distorted grid for lat/long coordinates over a projected map? If so, how?

Answer (score 5):

Not built in , AFAIK.
The way I do this is by creating a polygon shape file "grid" and then reprojecting it. So you could:

1. enable On-the-fly reprojection
2. Set the CRS to Lat/Lon
3. Use the Vector->Research Tools->Vector Grid to create a polygon grid at whatever interval is appropriate
4. Display the polygons with no fill, to show only the grid lines.
5. Return to your projected CRS, but keeping on the fly reprojection.

Now the Lat/Lon grid lines will display "distorted". If you also want to show coordinate labels on the grid lines, maybe this (somwhat old) [post](http://www.surfaces.co.il/grids-and-graticules-in-qgis/) will be helpful.

Comment: I have tried this method and sadly it doesn't work. The vector grid appears in a completely wrong place (even its coordinates are different, than what I set up in the dialog). I'm using a custom projected CRS for my project and wanted a lon/lat grid but I struggle to do it. What can be the reason?

Comment: The answer (from three years ago) refers to previous versions of QGIS. In recent version the ability to add multiple coordinate grids in different CRS is now built in. Check the Grid section (http://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/composer_items/composer_map.html#id3) of the QGIS documetation